# finish activity in android closing application

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

i want to  register on click register button then after new user is registered it goes back to login screen. for that i am using

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    username = eusername.getText().toString();
    email = eemail.getText().toString();
    mobile = emobile.getText().toString();
    password = epassword.getText().toString();
    registerViews();
    if(Validations.hasNoChars(username) && Validations.isEmail(email) && Validations.isMobileNumber(mobile) && Validations.isNotEmpty(password)) 
    {            
        new CreateUser().execute();
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //RegisterActivity.this.finish();

    }        

   else{
       Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  finish();
}
```

by this is switched to login screen but application closes. i don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: remove the  finish(); and try

Comment: Please post the code of your login page.

Comment: add an intent to go to the login screen.

Comment: just simple replace finish(); with onBackPressed(); then check....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(Validations.hasNoChars(username) && Validations.isEmail(email) && Validations.isMobileNumber(mobile) && Validations.isNotEmpty(password)) 
    {            
        new CreateUser().execute();
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Intent it=new Intent(this,login.class);
startActivity(it);

    }
```

Try to do this is your Async executes successfully it will transfer you to login activity.

Comment: This is not a proper solution because using this code you create new activity if you click on device back button your application once again back  on registration activity. so use onBackPressed();

Answer (score 1):

put finish(); in AsyncTask CreateUser() of onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to start login activity again. You must be finishing your login activity when starting the registration activity. Don't use finish() method while starting registration activity.